# dotnet core: When to use win10 over win7 RID?

Tags: .net-core

Without specifying `RuntimeIdentifiers` in my csproj I got `win7-x64` on both win7 and win10 machines. Both builds works (based on full framework).

I cannot find docs about - how to choose right RID and what is the difference between same-architecture-and-platform RIDs?

Comment: RIDs were an ugly bootstrapping detail, necessary because platform support was spotty in early .NETCore releases.  The end-goal is to provide a framework that supports execution on Windows, MacOS and various Linux flavors.  If it can't even be cross-platform on the same OS then that would be a missed goal :)   This needs to work just like java.exe or python.exe, you provide the DLL and the user provides whatever dotnet.exe is appropriate for his machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The.NET Core defaults to win7 for 
.NET Framework projects. In most cases, win10 and win7 runtime identifiers produce identical output, especially for .NET Framework projects.

The difference only matters if you depend on a NuGet packages that has Windows 10 specific APIs, which very few do, if any. Choose the runtime identifier that matches the minimum platform you support. E.g. if you don't intend to support Windows 7, 8, or 8.1, use win10.

Or use both if you want to support multiple platforms. RuntimeIdentifiers accepts a semicolon separated list.

Answer (score 0):

When you deliberately want your apps to be only used by Windows 10 users.

That can be pleasant if your apps do use Windows 10 specific features, which is not obvious for console and web apps, but might be typical when Microsoft introduces other project types such as GUI apps.

What I can think of at this moment is Windows 10 only things such as HTTP/2 support.